# Strategy for protecting client side web services

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I have `WCF` service called by `$.ajax({ url: 'service.svc?a=1', dataType: "JSONP", ...})` on one of the pages of `mysite.com` (100% client side stack). I want to limit service usage to mysite.com users only, is it possible to do it and if so how?

The only idea I have for now is introducing 'via' parameter, which'd help me to understand via which www my service was accessed.

P.S. I'm really struggling to come up with a good title, please fill free to change it!

Comment: I think what you want is a CSRF token, which you generate and validate on the server. This link may be of help to you - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: have a look at this blog post http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/04/wcf-restrict-which-clients-can-call.html
see if this is what you want

Comment: Interesting, but I've no such thing as 'known client' any client visiting the website is eligible to call the service. I'm not sure if people will be in position to install certs just for accessing my website. interesting anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting you application on IIS you can just add to you web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

For Access-Control-Allow-Origin you can set you application address: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://domain1.com" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

You can also reach the goal, writing behaviour which adds a specific header to each message. Here is a guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx

There is a constant CorsConstants.Origin, you can set your domain instead.

To check if response has required header you can use fiddler.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents malicious clients to fake this, this is just used by nice, secure browsers/clients. This doesn't secure anything.

Comment: @Dhaval Patel I really like it. I'll give it a go anyway.

Comment: @user3455395 as I already said, this doesn't secure anything! Read: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/. The Origin header can be set to anything by tools like curl etc. CORS (as this "solution" is called)   is just a method to allow cross-domain AJAX calls. Not to secure your content!

Answer (score 3):

We have developed a web based tool and we consume data through WCF service but we are not directly consume WCF service because it's REST service and we have not implemented any security in service. so, call service different way.

1) we have created a different but required handler files in same project

2) This handler file call our WCF service

3) As our tool is web based so we are checking session id when we call handler

4) If session id match then we pass data else we show session expire message

Please let me know if you still unclear about this concept.

Comment: Other way is through IIS you can allow only your site(mysite.com) host server IP address. This way if request come form other IP your IIS block request

Comment: But the question talks about 100% client side code, so blocking/whitelisting on IP is useless.

Comment: Also, any malicious user can just collect a session token from you app by visiting the page once, and then use the token to call the handler whenever they want (and load new session token).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to force your visitors to login/authenticate first: you can't.

To be able to limit usage to a certain group of users (in you case visitors of mysite.com), the users need to send something (key, password, token) to you service to identify themselves. If you store this token in your client side app (eg. javascript) people can just extract the token and use it whatever way they like. So that isn't possible. Neither can you trust any data send by a browser (eg. via param) because it can always be faked with simple tools. Those are pretty much all the options you have.

The real question is, why would you want to secure this content if it already is publicly available trough the website itself? One could easily build a simple scraper to get your content if they wanted to.

Comment: the main and only reason I wont to prevent data scrapping. the format in which data gets displayed to the users (canvas, stateless jquery controls etc.) will require quite a lot of effort to 'reverse-engineer' it to the source data, while calling the service directly will get them the data just for free. My best bet for now is to use ashx handlers but before I just wanted to make sure there isn't a better option.

Comment: Yes sure, if you just return a half rendered page, you don't expose the "raw" api data. But the question was if it was possbile to secure your data api, which you can't because of the stuff mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate user and generate one time token with sliding expiration time.Put that token into db with authenticated user and then send that token with each service request to authorize user.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't make a 100% bulletproof solution in principle unless you implement moderated user accounts, here is an approach I used to thwart hotlinking on my server. And it's not about referers.

My server implements `ETag` headers and `304 Not Modified` headers for certain files which would otherwise suffice with a timed cache. This is to save bandwidth and still see what was accessed. Then, the user's route to target is tracked at server side. Iff the milestones are met, the user is given a `credit` to access the expensive resource. The credits can add, so that simultaneous accesses will work. 
Besides this, I also set cookies to the user's browser during the route and test them later. Fake clients are notoriously bad at cookies, if they know them at all.

Remember, there is no perfect solution, but I believe that if you implement this, your server won't get overloaded. I should know, 99% of my requests are stolen, this filtering works!